# Python Only last line is written to file

Tags: python, google-maps, python-2.7

When I do print all my text is shown but when written to file only the last step is written.

```
 import json, urllib
from urllib import urlencode
import googlemaps
start = "Bridgewater, Sa, Australia"
finish = "Stirling, SA, Australia"

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?%s' % urlencode((
            ('origin', start),
            ('destination', finish)
 ))
ur = urllib.urlopen(url)
result = json.load(ur)

for i in range (0, len (result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'])):
    j = result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][i]['html_instructions'] 
    print j
output = open("output.html", "w")
output.write(j)
output.close()
```

I have also tried

```
   output.write("%s\n" %  j)
```

I get an error and

```
   output.write(result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][i]['html_instructions'])
```

Shows only last step

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are writing to file outside the for loop, so `j` contains value only for the last iteration and hence you only write the last line to the file.

You should instead open the file before the loop, and write to file inside the loop , also would be good to use `with` statement to open the file , so that closing is automatically handled. Example -

```
with open("output.html", "w") as output:
    for i in range (0, len (result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'])):
        j = result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][i]['html_instructions'] 
        print j 
        output.write(j + '\n')
```

Comment: Perfect thanks is there a way to add a new line after each step?

Comment: Thank you . Glad I could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You write only the last line, because, the write is outside your for-loop:

```
with open("output.html", "w") as output:
   for step in result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']:
       print step['html_instructions'] 
       output.write(step['html_instructions']+'\n')
```